# How to run different test suits by parameter?

Tags: java, selenium, junit4

I have some code running selenium testing. My tests run with Junit 4.12 with @RunWith and @Suite annotations.
Up until now I was running the test suite with 3 separate tests on one machine.
I now have to run my tests on multiple machines some are setup without a GPU.
As one of my tests depends on a GPU so I would like to be able to automatically omit the test when I run the suit on machines without GPU.

here my code at the moment -

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
        Test1_With_GPU.class,
        Test2_Without_GPU.class,
        Test3_Without_GPU.class
})
```

is there any way to have another set of suits:

```
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
        Test2_Without_GPU.class,
        Test3_Without_GPU.class
})
```

and run the suite according to systemProperties in pom.xml

```
<systemProperties>
    <property>
         <name>runWithGPU</name>
         <value>${runWithGPU}</value>
   </property>
</systemProperties>
```

so that when `runWithGPU==True` I will run the first suite, but when `runWithGPU==False` I will run the second suite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out how to skip the test by adding the following line in my code:

```
public void test() {
        assumeThat(System.getProperty("RUN_TEST_1"), CoreMatchers.is("True"));
        // rest of code here
}
```

Now my code run skips the test if I run `mvn test -DRUN_TEST_1=False`.

Hope this will help someone in the future.